# Is there anything to be aware of in changing the underlying physical storage of database files in a SQL AG system?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

The underlying physical storage in my SQL Server 2019 Availability Group databases needs to be changed on **one** of the nodes of my cluster.

Drive name, file path all remain the same for the database files, nothing else changing.

Is there anything I need to be careful about, being an AG replica on a Windows cluster?

My plan is to:

- take FULL backups of the databases as they are (i.e. in the AG, not removing them)
- Shutdown the services on **both** nodes
- Confirm that I cannot connect to either node in SSMS
- Swap the storage and physically copy the database files from old to new storage
- Start the services

Have I missed anything I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special due to the use of an Availability Group as it does not require anything special from storage. So long as the paths remain the same and security is applied appropriately, as you've stated they will, there should be no issues.